how do i retain my original image dimensions while saving the same image using matplotlib?
I'm trying to augment an image and then resave it using matplotlib,
but while i try save the image, matplotlib changes its dimensions and thereby making my augements incorrect.
here's my code, Hoping some one can help.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open( "D:\\ML_project\\pro\\dataset\\training\\images\\000000.png" );
width , height = img.size
print(img.size)

plt.figure(figsize = (width /120 , height/ 120));
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', bottom=False, top=False, left=False, 
right=False,labelbottom=False, labeltop=False, labelleft=False, labelright=False)

plt.axis("off")
plt.imshow(img,aspect="auto")
plt.savefig("D:\\ML_project\\pro\\dataset2\\training\\images\\000000.png",dpi = 120,bbox_inches = "tight",pad_inches = 0);

img =  Image.open( "D:\\ML_project\\pro\\dataset2\\training\\images\\000000.png" );
print(img.size)

The outputs i get for the two print statements are : (1224, 370) and
(948, 284)

You are saving a figure window, not an image. Use imsave to save an image.

don't use matplotlib for this. matplotlib is for plotting, not for saving images. use a different library. imageio seems popular, and so is PIL.

I am not so sure it is Matplotlib. Looking in the code it looks like the figures are saved in whatever file format is in the file path or forced to a pdf format and I think that is when the compression is occuring: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.8.4/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py#L2745-L2766
https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/#4Concepts.EncodingCompression
def savefig(self, figure=None, **kwargs):
    """
    Save a `.Figure` to this file as a new page.

    Any other keyword arguments are passed to `~.Figure.savefig`.

    Parameters
    ----------
    figure : `.Figure` or int, default: the active figure
        The figure, or index of the figure, that is saved to the file.
    """
    if not isinstance(figure, Figure):
        if figure is None:
            manager = Gcf.get_active()
        else:
            manager = Gcf.get_fig_manager(figure)
        if manager is None:
            raise ValueError(f"No figure {figure}")
        figure = manager.canvas.figure
    # Force use of pdf backend, as PdfPages is tightly coupled with it.
    with cbook._setattr_cm(figure, canvas=FigureCanvasPdf(figure)):
        figure.savefig(self, format="pdf", **kwargs) 

You could try this mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = {width, height} or mpl.rcParams['pdf.compression'] = False
    def savefig(self, fname, *, transparent=None, **kwargs):
    """
    Save the current figure.

    Call signature::

      savefig(fname, *, transparent=None, dpi='figure', format=None,
              metadata=None, bbox_inches=None, pad_inches=0.1,
              facecolor='auto', edgecolor='auto', backend=None,
              **kwargs
             )

    The available output formats depend on the backend being used.

    Parameters
    ----------
    fname : str or path-like or binary file-like
        A path, or a Python file-like object, or
        possibly some backend-dependent object such as
        `matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages`.

        If *format* is set, it determines the output format, and the file
        is saved as *fname*.  Note that *fname* is used verbatim, and there
        is no attempt to make the extension, if any, of *fname* match
        *format*, and no extension is appended.

        If *format* is not set, then the format is inferred from the
        extension of *fname*, if there is one.  If *format* is not
        set and *fname* has no extension, then the file is saved with
        :rc:`savefig.format` and the appropriate extension is appended to
        *fname*.

    Other Parameters
    ----------------
    transparent : bool, default: :rc:`savefig.transparent`
        If *True*, the Axes patches will all be transparent; the
        Figure patch will also be transparent unless *facecolor*
        and/or *edgecolor* are specified via kwargs.

        If *False* has no effect and the color of the Axes and
        Figure patches are unchanged (unless the Figure patch
        is specified via the *facecolor* and/or *edgecolor* keyword
        arguments in which case those colors are used).

        The transparency of these patches will be restored to their
        original values upon exit of this function.

        This is useful, for example, for displaying
        a plot on top of a colored background on a web page.

    dpi : float or 'figure', default: :rc:`savefig.dpi`
        The resolution in dots per inch.  If 'figure', use the figure's
        dpi value.

    format : str
        The file format, e.g. 'png', 'pdf', 'svg', ... The behavior when
        this is unset is documented under *fname*.

    metadata : dict, optional
        Key/value pairs to store in the image metadata. The supported keys
        and defaults depend on the image format and backend:

        - 'png' with Agg backend: See the parameter ``metadata`` of
          `~.FigureCanvasAgg.print_png`.
        - 'pdf' with pdf backend: See the parameter ``metadata`` of
          `~.backend_pdf.PdfPages`.
        - 'svg' with svg backend: See the parameter ``metadata`` of
          `~.FigureCanvasSVG.print_svg`.
        - 'eps' and 'ps' with PS backend: Only 'Creator' is supported.

        Not supported for 'pgf', 'raw', and 'rgba' as those formats do not support
        embedding metadata.
        Does not currently support 'jpg', 'tiff', or 'webp', but may include
        embedding EXIF metadata in the future.

    bbox_inches : str or `.Bbox`, default: :rc:`savefig.bbox`
        Bounding box in inches: only the given portion of the figure is
        saved.  If 'tight', try to figure out the tight bbox of the figure.

    pad_inches : float or 'layout', default: :rc:`savefig.pad_inches`
        Amount of padding in inches around the figure when bbox_inches is
        'tight'. If 'layout' use the padding from the constrained or
        compressed layout engine; ignored if one of those engines is not in
        use.

    facecolor : color or 'auto', default: :rc:`savefig.facecolor`
        The facecolor of the figure.  If 'auto', use the current figure
        facecolor.

    edgecolor : color or 'auto', default: :rc:`savefig.edgecolor`
        The edgecolor of the figure.  If 'auto', use the current figure
        edgecolor.

    backend : str, optional
        Use a non-default backend to render the file, e.g. to render a
        png file with the "cairo" backend rather than the default "agg",
        or a pdf file with the "pgf" backend rather than the default
        "pdf".  Note that the default backend is normally sufficient.  See
        :ref:`the-builtin-backends` for a list of valid backends for each
        file format.  Custom backends can be referenced as "module://...".

    orientation : {'landscape', 'portrait'}
        Currently only supported by the postscript backend.

    papertype : str
        One of 'letter', 'legal', 'executive', 'ledger', 'a0' through
        'a10', 'b0' through 'b10'. Only supported for postscript
        output.

    bbox_extra_artists : list of `~matplotlib.artist.Artist`, optional
        A list of extra artists that will be considered when the
        tight bbox is calculated.

    pil_kwargs : dict, optional
        Additional keyword arguments that are passed to
        `PIL.Image.Image.save` when saving the figure.

    """

    kwargs.setdefault('dpi', mpl.rcParams['savefig.dpi'])
    if transparent is None:
        transparent = mpl.rcParams['savefig.transparent']

    with ExitStack() as stack:
        if transparent:
            def _recursively_make_subfig_transparent(exit_stack, subfig):
                exit_stack.enter_context(
                    subfig.patch._cm_set(
                        facecolor="none", edgecolor="none"))
                for ax in subfig.axes:
                    exit_stack.enter_context(
                        ax.patch._cm_set(
                            facecolor="none", edgecolor="none"))
                for sub_subfig in subfig.subfigs:
                    _recursively_make_subfig_transparent(
                        exit_stack, sub_subfig)

            def _recursively_make_axes_transparent(exit_stack, ax):
                exit_stack.enter_context(
                    ax.patch._cm_set(facecolor="none", edgecolor="none"))
                for child_ax in ax.child_axes:
                    exit_stack.enter_context(
                        child_ax.patch._cm_set(
                            facecolor="none", edgecolor="none"))
                for child_childax in ax.child_axes:
                    _recursively_make_axes_transparent(
                        exit_stack, child_childax)

            kwargs.setdefault('facecolor', 'none')
            kwargs.setdefault('edgecolor', 'none')
            # set subfigure to appear transparent in printed image
            for subfig in self.subfigs:
                _recursively_make_subfig_transparent(stack, subfig)
            # set axes to be transparent
            for ax in self.axes:
                _recursively_make_axes_transparent(stack, ax)
        self.canvas.print_figure(fname, **kwargs)

